# Which language is used to make google docs and box.net?

Tags: google-docs

I want to know how and which things are used to make google docs and `box.net` ?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the UI functionality comes from using Javascript and HTML's DOM together with AJAX, a technique for using JS to make additional requests of the server without reloading the page.

In terms of the back-end languages (that provide the dynamic content) box.net returns `PHPSESSID` as part of it's set-cookie http response. They're also running nginx. So I would suspect one of the many PHP frameworks as being in use.

As for google docs, Google are known to use python quite extensively. Google's "App Engine" uses Python or Java as its languages (I believe Python was added first). So I suspect they use some customised form of python based on their own instance of their own app engine. Their http headers give nothing away, except that the `Server: GSE` line.

Answer (score 1):

According to [HowStuffWorks](http://communication.howstuffworks.com/google-docs5.htm), Google Docs uses Java for the backend and JavaScript for the front end. Of course, HTML is in the mix there as well.

As for the database it uses, Google won't say. It will use the cloud though, we can be sure of that.